# Scripting Runbook description

Tags: powershell, azure

Currently I am in the process of getting into Service Management Automation (SMA) which is principally similar to Azure. Is anyone able to tell me, when I upload my runbook to the SMA portal via the powershell cmdlets how I may enter a 'description'. 
Perhaps I have overlooked the appropriate cmdlet but I did not find an appropriate parameter in either:
 - Import-SmaRunbook,
 - Publish-SmaRunbook or 
 - Edit-SmaRunbook
one of which would have been the logical place to include such a parameter.
Naturally, I know that the description may be directly entered via the portal (manually), however automating the entire process would be better :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across the answer to my question (How to automate editing Runbook descriptions). 
To automate the editing of the Runbook description the Set-SmaRunbookConfiguration cmdlet can be used. 
Interestingly enough it can also be used to switch on the Progress, Verbose or Debug logging aswell.

For details:
[Technet Library][https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn502602%28v=sc.20%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396][1](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn502602%28v=sc.20%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)